# Subsetting Data frame or matrix based on criteria of values

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subset

Suppose I have a matrix or a data frame and I want only those values that are greater than 15 and no values between 85 and 90 both inclusive

```
a<-matrix(1:100,nrow = 10,  ncol = 10)
rownames(a) <- LETTERS[1:10]
colnames(a) <- LETTERS[1:10]
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J
A  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
B  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
C  3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
D  4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
E  5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
F  6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86  96
G  7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87  97
H  8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
I  9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
J 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

## Note: You can convert it into dataframe if you know this kind of operation is possible in dataframe

Now I want My result in such a format that only those values that are greater than 5 and less than 85 retain and all else got deleted and replaced with blank space.
My desired out is like below

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J
A    11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
B    12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
C    13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
D    14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
E  5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
F  6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76     96
G  7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77     97
H  8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78     98
I  9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79     99
J 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80    100
```

Is there any kind of function in R which can take my condition and produce the desired result. I want to change code according to problem . I searched it over stack flow but didn't find something like this. I don't want to format based on rows or column. 
I tried 
a[a> 5 & a!=c(85:90)]
but this give me values and looses the structure.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the 'a' is `matrix`, we can assign the values of 'a' `%in%` 86:90 or `|` less than 5 (`a < 5`) to NA.  Here, I am not assigning it to `''` as it will change the class from `numeric` to `character`.  Also, assigning to `NA` would be useful for later processing.

```
a[a %in% 86:90 | a<5] <- NA
```

However, if we need it to be `''`

```
a[a %in% 86:90 | a<5] <- ""
```

If we are using a `data.frame`

```
a1 <- as.data.frame(a)
a1[] <- lapply(a1, function(x) replace(x, x %in% 86:90| x <5, ""))
a1
#   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J
#A    11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
#B    12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
#C    13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
#D    14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
#E  5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
#F  6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76     96
#G  7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77     97
#H  8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78     98
#I  9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79     99
#J 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80    100
```

NOTE: This changes the `class` of each column to `character`

---

In the OP's code, `a!=c(85:90)` will not work as intended as the `85:90` will recycle to the length of the 'a' and the comparison will be between the corresponding values in the recycled value and 'a'.  Instead, we need to use `%in%` for a `vector` with `length` > 1.

Comment: But it changes the class of matrix values to character

Comment: @user110244 It is already mentioned in my post if you read it carefully.  The `''` is a character.  It is not possible to mix a character and numeric in a column without converting to 'character'

Comment: any way to mix space and interger in R.

Comment: No there is no way to mix space and integer in R . You can have different column types in R as a dataframe but can't mix two type in a single column.

Comment: @user110244 No, it is not useful.  Just use `NA`  and you can subset if you wanted with `?is.na` or `?complete.cases` etc

Comment: @user110244 If you really really wanted to do, place it in a `list` i.e. `a1[] <- lapply(a1, function(x) {i1 <- x %in% 86:90| x < 5; x1 <- x; x1[i1] <- ""; x[i1] <- as.list(x1[i1]); x }); a1`

Comment: @akrun what is the purpose of writing a1[ ] ? what does this mean ? please tell me . I am a newbie

Comment: @user110244  It is to preserve the structure of the original dataset.